ELK Algorithm Properties Fine Tuning to straighten Nodes connections
I am using ELK Layout view in an eclipse workbench project to arrange inputs outputs and blocks. The issue is that the result is still not perfect and a manual arrangement is needed. My question is which other properties even advanced can i change to get a better picture. ELK Layered is the algorithm i use, is maybe another algorithm needed like ELK tree that can improve the straightness of the connections and maybe bring them closer to the Blocks they are assigned to.
In the pictures are the not-so-perfect arrangements as well as the configured ELK properties.[layout result[layout2[elk-elk-propertiesproperties](https://i.sstatic.net/Tp5zZTfJ.jpg)](https://i.sstatic.net/Gk3OBQEu.jpg)](https://i.sstatic.net/pBWuAulf.jpg)
i used chatgpt to finetune the properties no better result could be reached. I changed the Edge.routing to Polyline and Node.placement.strategy to LinearSegments
